# why do merged videos become much large

Tags: rendering, video

I have five MP4 videos that I merge into one. The five files were about 50MB total, but when I merge them the file is ~250MB.  I'm using the same encoding, and medium quality output. Any idea why merging in blender quintuples the file size?

There are other questions on here about file size, but the answers all talk about changing the animation in some way, or using a different encoding.

I am just trying to merge MP4s and have the merged file about the same size as the input files combined.

Comment: I don't think blender explicitly let's you set the bitrate, other editors like resolve or shotcut will give you more control over quality settings.

Comment: You should be able to see in the file properties what the source files' bitrate is, just match up with the highest quality clip and it should be pretty close

Comment: @AllenSimpson, thank you, I will check that later to see if it fixes the problem, and edit the question once I do.